# preferred way of designing model in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a very simple model in Django with 3 fields. The issue is that I have dozens of billions of data that needs to be stored in the table associated with that model in Postgresql database. I stored around 100 millions of rows, and then my server first got sluggish and then gave me "Nginx 505 bad gateway" when clicking on that table in Django admin or requesting data using API.

I was wondering what is the best way to handle this simple scenario of having massive data in Django. What's the best model. Should I split my model in order to split my table?

Thanks,

Comment: A table with tens of billions of rows can be fine. It depends on your use case - what data you're storing, and how you need to access it. Perhaps you can tell us more about those things?

Comment: Its intraday stock market data for different symbols. Just raw data. And enquiries based on symbol and time interval